# Does anyone have this map file and launch file for turtlebot?

Tags: navigation, mapping, roslaunch, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261333/does-anyone-have-this-map-file-and-launch-file-for-turtlebot?/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can download it by`sudo apt-get install ros-<ros_version>-turtlebot-gazebo ros-<ros_version>-turtlebot-simulation`
Replace <ros_version> with the version you are using for ROS e.g. Indigo

---

Originally posted by [dgangwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30302/dgangwar/) with karma: 18 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0